# how to only allow long click be focusable

Tags: android

So what I would like to do is have a list and in the listview each row will have a few edittexts that if a user long clicks on one then I can show the softkeyboard and do validation post it being done. I'm not sure how to do this as I know you can globally make an edit text not editable but I want it editable via long click only. Do I need to take the source code for View and make a new view type for this? Is there a simpler solution?

Answer (score 0):

Set all of the EditText's focusableInTouchMode to false.

Add the following fields to your class.

```
protected TimeAnimator timer = new TimeAnimator();
protected int longPressTime = 1000; //in millisecond
protected int moveTol = 50; //in pixel
protected float startX;
protected float startY;
protected View pressedView;
```

Add an OnTouchListener with following onTouch method to all of the
    EditTexts.

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent e){
    switch(e.getActionMasked()){
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            timer.start();
            startX = e.getX();
            startY = e.getY();
            pressedView = v;
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            if(Math.abs(startX-e.getX()) > moveTol || Math.abs(startY-e.getY()) > moveTol){
                timer.end(); //Abandon this press because it moves beyond tolerance
            }
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            timer.end();
            break;
        default: break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Make your class implements TimeListener and add the following onTimeUpdate method.

```
public void onTimeUpdate(TimeAnimator timer, long t, long dt){
    if(t >= longPressTime){
        timer.end();
        pressedView.requestFocus();
    }
}
```

Add this line to your class's constructor.

```
timer.setTimeListener(this);
```

Comment: if requestfocus does this already then why not add an onlongclicktouchlistener and requestfocus that way?

Comment: Because i didn't know there is an onlongclicktouchlistener. It may be a good way.